# Unital C*-Algebras: Multiplier Algebra

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-algebras, c-star-algebras

Given a C*-algebra $\mathcal{A}$.

Multiplier Algebra:
$$\mathcal{M}(\mathcal{A}):=\{(L,R)\in\mathcal{B}(\mathcal{A})^2:\ldots\}$$

We know already:
It is the largest unitization of the algebra.
A unitization has the algebra as essential ideal.

For unital algebras:
$$1\in\mathcal{A}:\quad\mathcal{A}=\mathcal{M}(\mathcal{A})$$

Clearly we have:
Then the smallest unitization is the algebra.
How to check that it is also the multiplier algebra?

Comment: It is again the unital algebra $\mathcal{A}$. One can see by the fact that the multiplier algebra $\mathcal{M}(\mathcal{A})$ can be realized as the set of two-sided multipliers in the enveloping von Neumann algebra of $\mathcal{A}$.

Comment: @Mathematician42: I accidentally phrased it wrongly. I meant: "How to check ...?"

Comment: I'm not sure what the question is, you write $1\in\mathcal A: \mathcal A=\mathcal M(\mathcal A)$ and then it looks like you are asking how to check $\mathcal A=\mathcal{M(A)}$?

Comment: He is asking how to show that if $\mathcal{A}$ is unital, that $\mathcal{M}(\mathcal{A})=\mathcal{A}$. You could verify that $\mathcal{A}$ satisfies the universal property of $\mathcal{M}(\mathcal{A})$. I don't remember this universal property by heart, but google probably does. I recall doing this as an exercise once.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$\mathcal A$ is an ideal in $\mathcal{M(A)}$. Note that the double centraliser corresponding to $1$ is the unit in $\mathcal{M(A)}$, so $\mathcal A$ is an ideal that contains the unit and so must be the entire space.

To see that with: $L_1(a)=1\cdot a$, $R_1(a)=a\cdot 1$ one gets that $L,R\ =\mathrm{id}$ and then $(L,R)=1_{\mathcal{M(A)}}$.

Comment: A representation theory perspective. If you view $A$ as a Hilbert module, then $\mathcal{K}(A)$ is isomorphic to $A$ as a C*-algebra. Clearly, the multiplier algebra of $\mathcal{K}(A)$ is all the adjointable operators, but since the unit is compact, these are all compact.

Comment: how to prove A is an ideal of M(A)

Comment: Let $a\in\mathcal A$ correspond to $(L_a,R_a) \in \mathcal{M(A)}$. Let $(L,R)$ be in $\mathcal{M(A)}$. We want to show that $(L_a,R_a)\cdot (L,R)$ and $(L,R)\cdot(L_a,R_a)$ correspond to elements of $\mathcal A$. Well what is the $L$ part of $(L,R)\cdot (L_a,R_a)$? It is defined via $L\circ L_a$, note $L(L_a(x))=L(ax)=L(a)x= L_{L(a)}(x)$. Similarly $R\circ R_a = R_{R(a)}$. So $(L,R)\cdot (L_a,R_a)= (L_{L(a)},R_{R(a)})$. Verify in the same manner that $(L_a,R_a)\cdot (L,R) = (L_{R(a)},R_{L(a)})$.